# Hierarchical table column in Java

Tags: java, grid, hierarchical

Is there any Java library that supports hierarchical column?

For example (the first three row are columns) :

```
------------------------------------------------
2008                                           |
------------------------------------------------
January               | February               |
------------------------------------------------
Week1 | Week2 | Week3 | Week 1 | Week2 | Week3 |
------------------------------------------------
10    | 20    | 14    | 12     | 15    | 3     |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Good question.  Sometimes it is called a hierarchical grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be a [JXTree](http://javadesktop.org/swinglabs/build/weekly/latest/swingx-HEAD/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTree.html) from [SwingLab](https://swinglabs.dev.java.net/) could approach what you are looking for.

Illustration [here](http://avatar21.superihost.com/index.php?entry=entry060514-170809), from the [Swingx](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) project

http://avatar21.superihost.com/images/JXTableJXTreeTable.png

Answer (score 0):

[Infragistics WebGrid for JSF](http://www.infragistics.com/java/netadvantage/jsf/webgridoverview.aspx):

[alt text http://www.infragistics.com/uploadedImages/Products/NetAdvantage_for_JSF/Features/WebGrid/Gallery/WebGrid_Hierarchical.png](http://www.infragistics.com/uploadedImages/Products/NetAdvantage_for_JSF/Features/WebGrid/Gallery/WebGrid_Hierarchical.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Estima Visual Java/SWING Components Library 4.0](http://www.eltima.com/products/screenshots/visual-java-library/):
[image: New powerful Java Table Component]
<sub>(source: [eltima.com](http://www.eltima.com/images/screenshots/ELTable.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a JavaEE solution you might want to have a look at [[fleXive]](http://www.flexive.org), an open source (LGPL for the framework and GPL for the optional backend with visual editors).
Please feel free to ask any questions on the [forums](http://forum.flexive.org).

[image: content editing]
<sub>(source: [flexive.org](http://www.flexive.org/fileadmin/screenshots/flexive_cp_screenshot_04.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. Actually I need it for my desktop-based application. Currently I'm evaluating SWT table, but seems it does not support hierarchical table column. Maybe I'll take a look at Swing JTable.

Answer (score 0):

Or just follow this tutorial to use native JTable and JTree together:
[java_sun_articles_treetable1](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/index.html)